# target link libraries for C++

Tags: c++, catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a very simple C++ program and in the CMakelists.txt, my program works for both `target_link_libraries(myprogram ${roscpp_LIBRARIES})` and `target_link_libraries(myprogram ${catkin_LIBRARIES})`. Hence my question, for a C++ program which one is more suitable ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/178185/target-link-libraries-for-c++/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2014-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That depends on what your program needs.

Since roscpp is a catkin package, the latter does make sense. It will provide libraries from all the catkin packages you depend on.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2014-06-29**:
@joq What all does the catkin package include ? Is there a list ?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-06-29**:
Everything you found using `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp ... )`